# Android cannot compare dates with yyyy-MM-dd format

Tags: java, android, date

Android comparing date with `yyyy/MM/dd` format only force closes when compared with `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

```
final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",
Locale.getDefault());
String d = "2016/12/29";
expiryDate = (Date) formatter.parse(d);
```

Comment: How is possible .You already define "- - -" and your string "/ / / "

Comment: Have you tried `SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd",
Locale.getDefault());`? By the way, this is Java not php, right?

Comment: either change your string in "- - -" format or change your `SimpleDateFormat` in "/ / /"

Comment: I am getting the date from php server.

Comment: Please search StackOverflow before posting. This topic has been addressed many *hundreds* of times already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this one help you.

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

          try {

       Date finalStartTime = format.parse(YOUR_OLD_DATE);
       Date finalEndTime = format.parse(YOUR_NEW_DATE);

      if (finalEndTime.after(finalStartTime)) {
                   //your code
                }
         } catch (ParseException e) {
                        }
```

If still not worked let me know...

Comment: worked well thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Just Change "-" to "/" :

```
final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd",
    Locale.getDefault());
    String d = "2016/12/29";
 try {
        expiryDate = (Date) formatter.parse(d);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        //do something
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String d = "2016/12/29";
Date expiryDate = formatter.parse(d);
```

Comment: Wrong Answer . Check his question